# Using adjectives correctly

Tags: grammar

Should I use `effective` or `efficient` in the following sentence? Both of them are adjectives. However reading the definitions, I see that `effective` can be used as a NOUN while `efficient` is always an adjective. Does that really matter?

> This has been considered as an **effective** technique for many years
>
> This has been considered as an **efficient** technique for many years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the word 'effective' is *noun* or widely accepted as *noun*. Maybe, in rarest case it could be but still I doubt.

Both are adjective and mean different things.

> [effective (adj)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/effective) - *producing the result that is wanted or intended; producing a successful result.*

And,

> [efficient (adj)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/efficient) - *doing something well and thoroughly with no waste of time, money, or energy.*

The meanings specified here are clear.

Now your case...

> This has been considered as an effective technique for many years - the technique is effective because it proved the result what's wanted. In other words, its **effects** produced the results and that's how, it's **effective**.

The second one...

> This has been considered as an efficient technique for many years - the technique itself is efficient. It's about *being efficient* as the technique here is. However, *being efficient,* you are *effective** as well.

In other words, you are *efficient* to complete the task calculating 10 years' profit and loss of the company in an hour **AND** to prove yourself efficient, you must have *effective technique!* You may use some account software as that's an effective technique finish the task in said time.

Though both may go as an adjective to *technique*, it *depends on the context* what you want to say.

Answer (score 0):

A medicine can be effective, ie it has an effect. A secretary can be efficient, ie she does a lot of work. But you can't say she is effective.